# show how many duplicate words in google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

i have an exercise to do :

DELETE A LIST OF DUPLICATES

Create a variable of type Object:
var myObject = {}
or
var myObject = new Object ()

Using the Service SpreadsheetApp, get the list of fruits.

Fasten the 2 dimensional array and returned, create a new entry in your object for each new fruit.

If a fruit has already been listed, increment of 1, the counter value to this fruit.

Examples of structures for myObject:
myObject = {
"Apple": 1,
"Pear: 4
...dropoff Window
            }dropoff window

After completing all the fruit, buckle to myObject to build a data range with 2 columns (fruit, number of occurrences in the list) and display the result in columns D and E.

indication:
use the test: if (myFruit in myObject) {} to test if the result has already been listed or not.

this is the spreadsheet :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DV4E1.png

the result have to be like this :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqDFG.png

and this my code i'm blocked i don't what to do now please help me

```
//VARIABLE GLOBALE : DECLARATION DES FEUILLES

var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
var mySpread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

    // AJOUTE UN MENU PERSONNALIÉ DANS LA SPREADSHEET
    function onOpen(e) {
      ui.createMenu('Third-Step')
      .addItem('Del duplicates', 'deldup')
      .addToUi();
    }
    //SUPPRIMER LES DOUBLONS D’UNE LISTE
    
    function deldup() {
      var sheet =   SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      var result = [];
        
      if (sheet != null){
      var myFruit =    sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), 3).getValues();
                       sheet.getRange(1, 4, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 2).clearContent()
      var i =0;
      var myObject =  {
                   "Pomme":[i],
                   "Poire":[i],
                   "Banane":[i],
                   "Pêche":[i],
                   "Carotte":[i]
                   
                                 };                   
               for (var i=0; i< myObject.length; i++){
        
                             
                       
                 if(myFruit in myObject){
          
                  i += 1;
                 }
              result.push(myObject);
              } 
        sheet.getRange(1, 4, result.length, result[0].length).setValues(result);
      }
        
         else {
        sheet.toast("The Sheet is empty !!")
         }
    
      
    }
```

Comment: [How to ask & answer homework questions.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using this code(tested and working):

```
function deldup(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var i=0;
  var results =[["Pomme", i], ["Poire", i], ["Pêche", i]   ];
  if (sheet != null){

  var myFruit = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), 3).getValues();
  sheet.getRange(1, 4, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 2).clearContent();
  var flag = 0;

    for (var i=0; i< myFruit.length; i++){
        for(var j=0; j < myFruit[i].length; j++){
            if(results.length != 0){
                for(var k=0; k < 10; k++){
                   if(myFruit[i][j] == results[k][0]){
                        results[k][1]++;
                        flag = 1;
                        break;
                    }
                  if(flag == 0 ){
                    results.push([myFruit[i][j], 1]);
                  }
               }
           }
           else
           results.push([myFruit[i][j], 1]);
        }
     }
  sheet.getRange(1, 4, results.length, 2).setValues(results);
   }
  else {
    sheet.toast("The Sheet is empty !!")
  }
}
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Hello i got the good answer for my question the object have to be empty so if anyone else need it you can check it

```
//VARIABLE GLOBALE : DECLARATION DES FEUILLES

var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
var mySpread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

// AJOUTE UN MENU PERSONNALIÉ DANS LA SPREADSHEET
function onOpen(e) {
  ui.createMenu('Third-Step')
  .addItem('Del duplicates', 'deldup')
  .addToUi();
}
//SUPPRIMER LES DOUBLONS D’UNE LISTE

function deldup(){

  var sheet =    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var myObject = {};
  var myFruit =  sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), 3).getValues();

  sheet.getRange(1, 4, sheet.getLastRow() , 2).clearContent();

  for (var i=0; i< myFruit.length; i++){
    for(var j=0; j < myFruit[i].length; j++){

      if (myFruit[i][j] && myFruit[i][j] != "" && myFruit[i][j] != null ){

        if (myFruit[i][j] in myObject){
          myObject[myFruit[i][j]]++
        }else{
          myObject[myFruit[i][j]] = 1
        } 
      }
    }
  }

  var result = [];

  for (var fruit in myObject){   
    result.push([
      fruit,
      myObject[fruit]
    ])   
  } 

  sheet.getRange(1, 4, result.length, 2).setValues(result);
}
```

Hope that helps.