# How do I count the occurrences of a word in an array?

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, counting

I want to display my duplicate word in another array and how many times it is repeated.

For example, I have in my array `apple | apple | apple | bannane`. I want to display in my next array: `apple  | 3 | bannane | 1`

My code so far:

```
function suppd() {

  var monSpread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  var myObject = monSpread.getDataRange().getValues();
  var nvData = [];
  
  for(i in myObject){
    var row = myObject[i];
    var duplicate = false;
    for(j in nvData){
      if(row.join() == nvData[j].join()){
        duplicate = true;
      }
    }
    if(!duplicate){
      nvData.push(row);
    }
  }
  monSpread.getRange(1, 3, nvData.length, nvData[0].length).setValues(nvData);
}
```

Comment: So, in understandable terms, you want to get counts for all the words in the array?

Comment: You can refer to this question for solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27403099/show-how-many-duplicate-words-in-google-spreadsheet

Comment: @Oussama Posting exactly the same wording you used in the question as a comment does _not_ help in clarifying the question.

Comment: [How to ask & answer homework questions.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better to use an object to record what items are duplicates, and what the count is.  You are already checking for `NOT` a duplicate:

```
Logger.log("duplicate value is: " + duplicat);

if(!duplicate){
  nvData.push(row);
}
```

Add and ELSE condition:

```
var dupObject = {};
var countThisDuplicate = 0;

if(!duplicate){
  nvData.push(row)
} else {
  //Check if duplicate is already in the object
  Logger.log("The else part of the code ran!");
  if (dupObject[j]) {
    //If duplicate is already in the object, get the count, then add one to it
    countThisDuplicate = dupObject[j] + 1;
    dupObject[j] = countThisDuplicate;
  } else {
    //If duplicate is NOT already in the object, add the member with a count of one
    dupObject[j] = 1;
  };
};
```

I just threw this together and didn't test it, so it probably has errors.  It's just to give you an idea, and try to answer your question.  Hopefully it gives you the basic logic to solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you Sandy for reply me I can not integrate you'r code with my code are you can help me more plzz

Comment: Please put `Logger.log("My variable value is: " + variableName);` statements into your code, run the code, and then under the VIEW menu, look at the LOG.  Also, VIEW the EXECUTION TRANSCRIPT, and post what errors you are getting, and on what line.  I added `Logger.log()` example statements in the code in my answer above as an example.

Comment: This is a link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27403099/show-how-many-duplicate-words-in-google-spreadsheet/27420017#27420017